# How to import exported auth data into Firebase emulators?

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

Can Firebase emulators import "exported Firebase auth data"?

Firebase emulators imports exported Firestore data, which is exported to gCloud then downloaded to my machine. The emulators can also import the auth data it exports, but I can't figure out how to import the data I've exported from Firebase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is currently no way to import the `auth:export` format back into the emulator in bulk. At the moment it only can read its own export format (which allows it to persist user accounts between runs of the emulator suite).

This is a feature we'd like to add to the emulator at some point, but for the moment you'd have to build it yourself by processing the export.

Comment: Any updates? It'd be cool to see this feature added.